# Water and pressure

Tags: newtonian-gravity, pressure, water, fluid-statics, buoyancy

We know that as we go down the water volume, we see rise in pressure. It's because of gravity. Right?
But then if that's true why would the particle down the surface will apply the upthrust or buoyant force or upward force on the object?
And if the pressure difference is not only gravity, then shouldn't in space, water should keep moving up and down in itself?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602020/195139

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'the particle down the surface'? 2) By 'in space' do you mean in the absence of significant gravity? 3) What do you mean by 'keep moving up and down in itself'?

Comment: It's time to learn what is and how "to accept an answer as the best one".

Answer (score 2):

The increase of pressure with depth is due to gravity. A simplified explanation is as follows. A volume of liquid with height $h$ and horizontal area $A$ has a downwards force $F_1$ acting on it from the liquid above and an upwards force $F_2$ acting on it from the liquid below. The net force on this volume of liquid must be zero (otherwise it would move up or down) so

$$F_2 - F_1=Mg$$

where $M$ is the mass of the liquid. But $M=\rho Ah$ where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid. So

$$F_2-F_1=\rho Ahg$$

Dividing by the area $A$ gives us the pressure difference between the bottom and top of the volume of liquid with height $h$:

$$P_2-P_1=\rho hg$$

If we replace the volume of liquid with a solid object with volume $V=Ah$ then exactly the same pressure difference acts on this object, so the net upwards force exerted on the object by the liquid is

$$F_2-F_1=\rho Ahg=\rho Vg$$

which is the buoyancy force acting on the object.

Answer (score 1):

A water particle pushes upward on a buoyant object because the object is pushing down on the water particle due to gravity. If an object wasn't being pushed down by gravity, the water would not push up on it.

Comment: Yeah, why would even water apply that force?

Comment: Every force has an equal and opposite reaction. Gravity is forcing the object down onto the water. the water forces it back up. It's the same reason a table applies an upward force on a plate