# Why Earth is taken as Inertial Frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, estimation

I have seen the answers to this saying that the effect Earth's rotation is neglegible compared to Gravity. But isnt the answer to this should include that the relative acceleration between object under consideration and the observer on the ground is zero. As both have the same effect of Earths rotation.

Comment: Coriolus would beg to differ. Just a question of scale.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/629686/196140

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should not we apply pseudo-forces all the time as the Earth is a non-inertial frame of reference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629581/)

Comment: In what context are you asking? Ballistic trajectories, Twin Paradox, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the solution of basic problems in mechanics, the Earth's surface is often taken to be an inertial reference frame (and the acceleration due to gravity is sometimes assumed to be exactly $9.8$ m/s$^2$). But this is only approximately true. Due to the combined effects of (a) the Earth is not a perfect sphere and (b) the daily rotation of the Earth, there is difference of about $0.5\%$ between the apparent force of gravity at the poles and at the equator. This is a small effect, but is definitely measurable.

If you are solving problems that extend over significant distances compared to the size of the Earth (such as the ballistic trajectory of artillery shells, forces in the atmosphere, or spaceflight) then you can no longer treat the surface of the Earth as an inertial reference frame, and you definitely need to take into account the rotation of the Earth and effects that arise from this, such as Coriolis forces.

Answer (score 0):

No, because inertial frame basically means no motion or uniform motion, thus no acceleration and no force. If you consider relative acceleration, that won't be inertial frame by definition.